# Basic 3D OpenGL collision detection C++

Tags: c++, 3d, collision-detection

I'm currently in the process of developing a very basic 3D OpenGL game in C++ as part of a small college project. We don't get a lot of insight from the teachers however, and only very limited documentation, as well as a small timeframe, so I'm kind of a little lost here at the moment.

My game is a tank battle on an orthogonal plane that pretty much looks exactly like the image I sketched below. Each tank (A and B) can be controlled by a different player, and each one can shoot projectiles, which are supposed to influence the other tank's score upon collision.

[image]

My question is, what would be the simplest way of effectively implementing collisions for the tanks? (Tank vs tank, tank vs map boundaries and tank vs any kind of parallelepipedic object like the one in the center of the picture - and the same thing but applied to the projectiles shot from the tank turrets).

Ideally, without the need of using an external physics engine, but also accepted if the implementation can be done easily. At the moment, I'm solely using the GLUT library.

Answer (score 2):

Download and integrate Box2D (http://box2d.org) into your project.

Unless your project is to implement a physics engine, then don't bother doing it yourself. Your time will be much better spent learning how to integratate libraries and how proper physics engines work.

You can then easily use a box collider for your tanks, circle for projectiles and 4 lines for your perimeter.  You can create callbacks to notify you when a projectile has collided with another tank.

You will have to use forces and torques to move and rotate your tanks, rather than just updating their positions. But you would probably have to do that anyway if you were going to implement the physics yourself.